# Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$query

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem in CodeIgniter.

My code:

```
 <?php 
   $kullanici_yetki_id=$this->session->user_sess['id'];
   $result= array(
        $this->db->select('*'),
        $this->db->from('menuler'),
        $this->db->join('menu_yetki', 'menuler.menu_id=menu_yetki.menu_id'),
        $this->db->where('menuler.is_active', '1'),
        $this->db->where('user_id', $kullanici_yetki_id),
        $this->db->where('durum', "1"),
        $this->db->limit('1')   
                );      
        $sorgu=$this->db->query->$result();
        if($sorgu->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($sorgu as $row) {
            echo $row->menu_adi;

        } } else{
            echo "nope";
        }

      ?>
```

When I run it, it returns this error:

> Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$query
>
> Filename: admin/_leftmenu.php Line Number: 34
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\bireberberci\application\views\admin_leftmenu.php
>   Line: 34 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp64\www\bireberberci\application\controllers\admin\Home.php
>   Line: 16 Function: view
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\bireberberci\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

And this:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Method name must be a string
>
> Filename: admin/_leftmenu.php
>
> Line Number: 34

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the get() and your session part user_sess['id'] is wrong

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

```
<?php 

    class Example_model extends CI_Model {

        public function example() {
            $data = array();

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('menuler');
            $this->db->join('menu_yetki', 'menuler.menu_id=menu_yetki.menu_id');
            $this->db->where('menuler.is_active', '1');
            $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
            $this->db->where('durum', "1");
            $this->db->limit('1');

            $sorgu = $this->db->get();

            if($sorgu->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($sorgu->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row->menu_adi;
            } 

            } 

            return $data;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but your syntax is a tad off. You can refer to the manual about [query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) for more information.

Your biggest mistake was putting all the db calls into an array. This is much closer to what you want.

```
$kullanici_yetki_id = $this->session->userdata['id'];

$this->db->from('menuler');
$this->db->join('menu_yetki', 'menuler.menu_id=menu_yetki.menu_id');
$this->db->where('menuler.is_active', '1');
$this->db->where('user_id', $kullanici_yetki_id);
$this->db->where('durum', "1");
$this->db->limit('1');

$sorgu = $this->db->get();

if ($sorgu->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($sorgu->result() as $row) {
        echo $row->menu_adi;
    }
} else {
    echo "nope";
}
```